# Обратная функция нормального распределения

Tags: математика, теория-вероятностей

Помогите вывести обратную функцию нормального распределения.
[image: формула плотности функции нормального распределения]

Comment: Это вопрос по математике, а не по программированию.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну, если

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

то

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но... вам точно нужно именно это? Вас точно интересует не *erf(x)*?